# Uploading image (as data:image/png:base64) to webserver

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, file-upload

I have an image on a web page constructed like so:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64;...." />
```

The contents of the image come from the user pasting into the browser. My question is how do I then upload the image to the webserver (PHP if that matters).

Comment: do you mean pasting in a textarea for example? this sounds quite odd... could you explain the situation a little bit more?

Comment: I have an input that, when a user pastes image data into it (i.e. from clipboard - in Chrome only) itll assign the data to an image as a preview before it is uploaded

Comment: @Chris If you want to see an actual js code show what you already have, not just a small unrelated piece of it.

Comment: i totally understand now :) @Cheery has given you a pretty good answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Take the src attribute with javascript (or the data submitted by user)

2) Submit it to the server 'as is' or cut and submit everything after `base64;` (AJAX or POST, method GET is probably not very suitable here for large images)

3) Decode base64 on server side (everything after `base64;` if not cutted), save the result as binary - it is an image.

That's it.

ps: just a reminder - by careful with possible code injection. Check the submitted data or somebody will upload encoded php script. Disable php engine in the folder with uploads and verify that the final result is an actual image (with the help of GD library, for example). Even if the script can not run on your server it could be used for malicious requests to other servers with php scripts.

Comment: Thankyou, is there an easier way to prevent against code injection?

Comment: @Chris you have to validate the data before you save it on the server. As I wrote you could check that you are able to get the image width and height by GD module. Next step is not to save the data with file extension provided by the user. I would try to 'resize' the image without change of the parameters, saving the result. This way you can be sure that you have only the data passed through the GD.

Answer (score 1):

Just post the base 64 encoded text to your server.

You could save it as...

```
file_put_contents($image, base64_decode($str));
```